# mysql show processes

Tags: process, phpmyadmin, mysql

I don't have phpMyAdmin installed on a ubuntu server but want to show all mysql processed. I know that you can do a "show_processes" in phpMyAdmin but how can I do it via shell?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql -u USER -pPASS -P PORT -h HOST < "show processlist"
```

details:

```
-u = user
-p = password
-P = port number
-h = HOST
```

if you want to get the details via information_schema views,

```
sql="select * from information_schema.processlist where ???"
mysql -u USER -pPASS -P PORT -h HOST < $sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -uuser -p -e "show full processlist"
```

or

```
mysql -uuser -p -e "show processlist"
```